# Rapidfire and Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I implemented Devise and went through the instructions to install Rapidfire 
and for the application controller I have

```
def current_user
  current_user  #rb:7
end

def can_administer
  true # just for right now...
end
```

but on the page I get a something went wrong and if I look in the console it says

```
ActionView::Template::Error (stack level too deep)
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:7
```

which is the `current_user` line.

Can anyone tell me whats going on?

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a method called `current_user`, and you are returning the value of `current_user`.

Ruby doesn't require that you use parenthesis when calling methods.

```
current_user
```

is the same thing as

```
current_user()
```

You are calling the `current_user` function over and over and over again.

There is no reason for you to define a method called `current_user`, when devise gives that to you.

Comment: I ask because when i don't use that function i get an error saying it can't find my user_path

Comment: well my error is undefined local variable or method new_user_session_path

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? I can sign in it's only when i visit /Rapidfire that it blows up?

Comment: You need to add `devise_for :users` in your `routes.rb` file.

Comment: I have it there I have 
mount Rapidfire::Engine => "rapidfire"  
devise_for :users
root to:"welcome#index"

Comment: I think Rapidfire isnt' in the same session?
my code blows up here  <%if current_user %> something  <% else %> <%= link_to "Sign in", new_user_session_path %>  it blows up  on new_user session_path but I'm signed in?

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. I just skimmed the [documentation](https://github.com/code-mancers/rapidfire) and I can't find out what you are doing incorrectly.

Comment: Make sure that `new_user_session_path` is listen when you `rake routes`

Comment: yeah its there is like rapidfire doesn't know about devise for some reason.