# Rapidfire and Devise and rake routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, rapidfire-gem

This is stemming from [Rapidfire and Devise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22019767/rapidfire-and-devise)  I installed Devise on in my app and I can log in fine, but then I installed the `rapidfire` Gem and I can still log in with it installed, but when I got to `localhost::3000/rapidfire` I get an error saying the devise paths are not recognized. Can anyone help?

For the `application_controller`, I didn't include the `current_user` function they say here and set the `can_administer` function to return `true` like

```
#def current_user
#    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id])
# end

def can_administer?
 true
end
```

rake Routes shows this below

Prefix Verb

```
new_user_session Get /users/sign_in      

user_session

destroy_user_session

user_password

new_user_password

edit_user_password

cancel_user_registration

user_registration

new_user_registration

edit_user_registration

user_confirmation

new_user_confirmation

rapidfire

root Get /

Routes Rapidfire::Engine:
results_question_group
question_grou_quetions...
```

Comment: You mentioned in your previous question it complaining about a lack of `user_path`. You don't seem to have a `user` route.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a resource in your routes file for your `UsersController`.

Add something like

```
resources :users
```

to your `config/routes.rb` file. That should give you the `user` routes you are looking for.

Comment: even if I have devise_for :users in my routes.rb?

Comment: Devise controls authentication. It will not create a `UsersController` for you to `show`, `destroy` or anything else you would want to do with a normal resource. You need to create that yourself.

Comment: That didn't work I defined a Users controller resource and views and it gave me the same error.

Comment: Do you have the `user` route in your `rake routes`?

Comment: Yeah, Rapidfire just doesn't recognize the routes I have for some reason
I have a route  destroy_user_session_path  and before i go to /rapidfire it works.... maybe it's because rapidfire has its own root?

Comment: Might want to post a bug ticket then.

Comment: well instead of using the  link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_path
<%= lijnk_to "Sign out",  'users/sign_out', method :delete %> seems to work

Answer (score 1):

It's not recognizing your devise paths because Rapidfire sets it's own application root to its directory, rather than that of the application. You need to replace Rapidfire's app root with the actual application root.